# gobble option of listing when used via tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I use `tcolorbox` + `listings` to display code in a box.  I pass a `gobble` option to `listings`, which seems to be plainly ignored:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{tcblisting}{%
  listing only,
  title=Source,
  listing options={gobble=30}}
                                        some code
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[gobble=30]
                                        some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I missing to make `gobble` work?

Comment: Environment `tcblisting` internally stores its contents in a temp file and then uses `\lstinputlisting` to input it. From package manual of `listings`, sec. 8, unnumbered title _How to gobble characters_, option `gobble` has NO effect on `\lstinputlisting`.

Comment: Argh...  that's very unfortunate.  Thanks for the insight.